# firebase data patching on flutter not working

Tags: database, flutter, firebase

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = 
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('msgerstory').snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _usersStream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Something went wrong');
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Text("Loading");
          }

          return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(data['usrid']),
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Console::

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53782/-K_CbrO9z_A=/ws
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
I/FirebaseApp(12073): Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
I/flutter (12073): User is signed in!
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(12073): Google Play services out of date for com.rmessenger.rmessenger.  Requires 11925000 but found 11743470
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(12073): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 2
W/Firestore(12073): (24.1.2) [GrpcCallProvider]: Failed to update ssl context: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException: Google Play Services not available
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(12073): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/art     (12073): Before Android 4.1, method double java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextDouble(double, double) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
W/art     (12073): Before Android 4.1, method int java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextInt(int, int) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
W/art     (12073): Before Android 4.1, method long java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextLong(long, long) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
D/EGL_emulation(12073): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb1b85900: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x92991980)
W/Firestore(12073): (24.1.2) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(msgerstory order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
```

showing something went wrong.

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question and copy-paste the error output as well in the question itself?

Comment: ok I just edited

Comment: What's the specific error you're talking about?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.